# Dynamic loading of second selection box from the DB based on first selection box

Tags: odoo

Please correct the code  so as to load second selection box based on first selection.

```
          type_id        choice_id
            fruit          orange
            fruit          apple
            drinks         coffee
            drinks         tea
```

Now as part of requirement when user select fruit from the selection box , other selection box 'choice' should be loaded dynamically with  orange and apple only . Same way when user selects drinks as type then  coffee and tea should be loaded .

### .py file

```
         from osv import osv
         from osv import fields
         class solid_base(osv.osv):
              _name='solid.base'
              _columns={

                       'type_id':fields.many2one('solid.type','type'),
                       'choice_id':fields.many2one('solid.choice','choice'),

                       }
         solid_base()

         class solid_type(osv.osv):
             _rec_name='type_id'
             _name='solid.type'
             _columns={

                       'type_id':fields.char('Type :'),

                      }

        solid_type()


      class solid_choice(osv.osv):
           _rec_name='choice_id'
          _name='solid.choice'
          _columns={
                 'choice_id':fields.char('Choice :'),
                 'type_id':fields.many2one('solid.type','Type :'),

                   }

      solid_choice()
```

### XML

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <openerp>
     <data>

   <record model="ir.ui.view" id="solid_base_form">
       <field name="name">solid.base.form</field>
           <field name="model">solid.base</field>
           <field name="type">form</field>
           <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <form string="Solid Base">                     
          <field name="type_id" widget="selection"/>
          <field name="choice_id"  domain="[('type_id','=',type_id)]" widget="selection"/>
     </form>
         </field>
    </record>
    <record model="ir.ui.view" id="solid_base_tree">
        <field name="name">solid.base.tree</field>
        <field name="model">solid.base</field>
        <field name="type">tree</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <tree string="Solid Base">              
       <field name="type_id"/>
       <field name="choice_id"/>
            </tree>
       </field>
    </record>
    <record model="ir.ui.view" id="solid_choice_form">
           <field name="name">solid.choice.form</field>
           <field name="model">solid.choice</field>
           <field name="type">form</field>
           <field name="arch" type="xml">
               <form string="solid.choice">                    
                   <field name="type_id" />
               <field name="choice_id" />

     </form>
          </field>
    </record>



        <record model="ir.actions.act_window" id="action_solid_seq7">
        <field name="name">solid choice</field>
        <field name="res_model">solid.choice</field>
        <field name="view_type">form</field>
        <field name="view_mode">tree,form</field>
    </record>

    <record model="ir.actions.act_window" id="action_solid_seq6">
        <field name="name">solid base</field>
        <field name="res_model">solid.base</field>
        <field name="view_type">form</field>
        <field name="view_mode">tree,form</field>
    </record>


    <menuitem id="menu_solid_base_super_main"  name="Solid Base"/>
    <menuitem id="menu_solid_base_main" parent="menu_solid_base_super_main" name="New Solid Base"/>
    <menuitem id="menu_solid_base1" parent="menu_solid_base_main"
              name="New Solid Base1" action="action_solid_seq6"/>
              <menuitem id="menu_solid_base2" parent="menu_solid_base_main"
              name="New Solid Base2" action="action_solid_seq7"/>

</data>
```

### Error Log :

```
 OpenERP Server Error
Client Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Program Files\OpenERP 7.0-20131006-    231029\Server\server\openerp\addons\web\http.py", line 204, in dispatch
File "C:\Program Files\OpenERP 7.0-20131006- 231029\Server\server\openerp\addons\web\controllers\main.py", line 1132, in call_button
File "C:\Program Files\OpenERP 7.0-20131006-231029\Server\server\openerp\addons\web\controllers\main.py", line 1120, in _call_kw
   File "C:\Program Files\OpenERP 7.0-20131006-231029\Server\server\openerp\addons\web\session.py", line 42, in proxy
   File "C:\Program Files\OpenERP 7.0-20131006-231029\Server\server\openerp\addons\web\session.py", line 30, in proxy_method
   File "C:\Program Files\OpenERP 7.0-20131006-  231029\Server\server\openerp\addons\web\session.py", line 103, in send


   Server Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:\Program Files\OpenERP 7.0-20131006-231029\Server\server\openerp\addons\web\session.py", line 89, in send
   File "C:\Program Files\OpenERP 7.0-20131006-231029\Server\server\.\openerp\netsvc.py", line 292, in dispatch_rpc
   File "C:\Program Files\OpenERP 7.0-20131006-231029\Server\server\.\openerp\service\web_services.py", line 622, in dispatch
   File "C:\Program Files\OpenERP 7.0-20131006-231029\Server\server\.\openerp\service\security.py", line 40, in check
   File "C:\Program Files\OpenERP 7.0-20131006-231029\Server\server\.\openerp\pooler.py", line 49, in get_pool
   File "C:\Program Files\OpenERP 7.0-20131006-231029\Server\server\.\openerp\pooler.py", line 33, in get_db_and_pool
   File "C:\Program Files\OpenERP 7.0-20131006-231029\Server\server\.\openerp\modules\registry.py", line 192, in get
  File "C:\Program Files\OpenERP 7.0-20131006-231029\Server\server\.\openerp\modules\registry.py", line 218, in new
  File "C:\Program Files\OpenERP 7.0-20131006-231029\Server\server\.\openerp\modules\loading.py", line 350, in load_modules
  File "C:\Program Files\OpenERP 7.0-20131006-231029\Server\server\.\openerp\modules\loading.py", line 256, in load_marked_modules
  File "C:\Program Files\OpenERP 7.0-20131006-231029\Server\server\.\openerp\modules\loading.py", line 187, in load_module_graph
  File "C:\Program Files\OpenERP 7.0-20131006-231029\Server\server\.\openerp\modules\loading.py", line 74, in <lambda>
  File "C:\Program Files\OpenERP 7.0-20131006-231029\Server\server\.\openerp\modules\loading.py", line 124, in _load_data
  File "C:\Program Files\OpenERP 7.0-20131006-231029\Server\server\.\openerp\tools\convert.py", line 954, in convert_xml_import
  File "C:\Program Files\OpenERP 7.0-20131006-231029\Server\server\.\openerp\tools\convert.py", line 847, in parse
  File "C:\Program Files\OpenERP 7.0-20131006-231029\Server\server\.\openerp\tools\convert.py", line 814, in _tag_record
File "C:\Program Files\OpenERP 7.0-20131006-231029\Server\server\openerp\addons\base\ir\ir_model.py", line 937, in _update
  File "C:\Program Files\OpenERP 7.0-20131006-231029\Server\server\openerp\addons\base\ir\ir_ui_view.py", line 214, in write
  File "C:\Program Files\OpenERP 7.0-20131006-231029\Server\server\.\openerp\osv\orm.py", line 4205, in write
  File "C:\Program Files\OpenERP 7.0-20131006-231029\Server\server\.\openerp\osv\orm.py",  line 1548, in _validate
  except_orm: ('ValidateError', u'Error occurred while validating the field(s) arch:  Invalid XML for View Architecture!')
```

Answer (score 0):

Selection field have a static list.In your case, you should use a many2one field with widget='selection' in the view so that you can pass the value of one field to other for filtering
for example create tables for choice and type. Name field will be enough for these tables.In the choice table add a many2one relation to type table(say type_id) which is a required field. Then in the new.base table add these fields as many2one fields(say type_id and choice_id) and in the view for the field `<field name="type_id" widget='selection'/><field name="choice_id" domain="[('type_id','=',type_id)]" widget='selection'/>`

Comment: Tnank you. I will follow above steps and update here

Comment: OmaL Sir,   system throws error saying that  "except_orm: ('ValidateError', u'Error occurred while validating the field(s) arch: Invalid XML for View Architecture!')",  When I added, <field name="choice_id"  domain="[('type_id','=',type_id)]" widget="selection"/> ..  Note :  if I replace with  domain="[('type_id','=','drinks')] OR [('type_id','=','fruit')] , it works fine.Please help me

Comment: I have updated my query with error log.. it fails for [('type_id','=',type_id)]      However  With following piece of code it works fine. domain="[('type_id','=','drinks')] OR [('type_id','=','fruit')] OR domain="[('type_id','=',1)] OR [('type_id','=',2)]

Comment: I have sent my module to you . Probably it might helps you to investigate on error